# Check for, and add, missing timestamps to individual lines in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file in the following format:

```
ABCD 01206001022T01YA022T01YA022T07SO 09:20:38
ABCD 01206001022ACION 09:24:40
ABCD 04006001021S01UK 09:24:42
ABCD 7878696621321312 23213213213213
ABCD ASADSADSFSSDSSD 09:24:50
```

Basically except the first field, all other fields are different.

Requirement: I want timestamp on each line. If a timestamp is missing on any line, I want to append the timestamp of the previous line to the end of missing line (Example 4th line above). How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say "timestamp" you mean just the time of day? Nothing more elaborate such as the date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `awk` should do it:

```
awk '{ 
         if ( $NF ~ /[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/ ) {
            lasttime = $NF
            print
         } else {
            print $0, lasttime
         }
     }' < myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash solution in case that matters. It does make use of a single `awk`, but that could probably be refactored out if needed:

```
while read line ; do
  ncol=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $NF}')
  if [[ "$ncol" == *:*:* ]]; then
    tmstmp="$ncol"
    echo "$line"
    continue
  fi
  echo "$line $tmstmp"

done < 82031.txt
```

The file `82031.txt` includes the following:

```
ABCD 01206001022T01YA022T01YA022T07SO 09:20:38
ABCD 01206001022ACION 09:24:40
ABCD 04006001021S01UK 09:24:42
ABCD 7878696621321312 23213213213213
ABCD ASADSADSFSSDSSD 09:24:50
```

Running the above script produces the following:

```
ABCD 01206001022T01YA022T01YA022T07SO 09:20:38
ABCD 01206001022ACION 09:24:40
ABCD 04006001021S01UK 09:24:42
ABCD 7878696621321312 23213213213213 09:24:42
ABCD ASADSADSFSSDSSD 09:24:50
```

#### pure Bash solution

Here's an alternative that uses nothing but Bash. Instead of using `awk` to pull out the last column from a line of input from the .txt file, we're using Bash's `read` command on the `while` loop. The options `-ra` disable backslashes from being an escape character (`-r`) and the `-a` splits the input up using the `$IFS` separator, putting each atoms worth of text into an element in the array `${line[@]}`.

```
while IFS=" " read -ra line ; do
  ncol="${line[@]: -1:1}"
  if [[ "$ncol" == *:*:* ]]; then
    tmstmp="$ncol"
    echo "${line[@]}"
    continue
  fi
  echo "${line[@]} $tmstmp"

done < 82031.txt
```

This bit, `${line[@]: -1:1}` pulls out the last column of the array `${line[@]}`.

Comment: Using `read -a` to read into an array rather than string would be the way to eliminate the call to `awk`.

Comment: @jordanm - thanks I've added an example using your tip.

Answer (score 0):

One more bash solution

```
[[ ! -f $1 ]] && { echo -e "\tUsage:\t\n\t\t$0\t<input_file>\n"; exit 1; }

while read -ra line;
do
        if [[ ${line[@]} =~ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ ]]; then
                echo ${line[@]}
                lasttime=${line[@]: -1:1}
        else

                echo ${line[@]} $lasttime
        fi
done < $1
```